# PHP calculate array data

Tags: php, arrays

I am having trouble to calculate the sum of an array values 
my array is

```
$bar_chart_data = 
array(
    array(
        array("Data1",548.25),
        array("Data2",238.75),
        array("Data3",95.50),
        array("Data4",300.50),
        array("Data5",286.80),
        array("Data6",148.25)
        )
    );
```

I am using this php code to calculate the results but its always gives me **0**

```
$sumArray = array();
foreach ($bar_chart_data as $k=>$subArray) {
    foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
        $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
    }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

Comment: replace ` array("Data1",548.25)` with `"Data1"=>538.25` etc.

Comment: what result are you expecting exactly?

Comment: @rlanvin
the summation of the float values that are in the array

Comment: @FranzGleichmann i did but nothing happens

Comment: Why do you create a "sum array" if you want only a total? It looks like you are trying to get more than one sum?

Comment: @rlanvin that's right but i solve this part , my problem was with the summation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$id` is different in all iteration.

You have to use `$sumArray[$k]+=$value[1];`.

You also have to init `$sumArray[$k]` to `0` between your two `foreach`.

Comment: thats works perfect , accepted , now i know where my error is , thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have an array containing a sub-array and you want to get the sum of all the values in each of the sub-arrays.

I suggest you use an associative sub-array to make the task easier.

```
$bar_chart_data = array(
    array(
        "Data1" => 548.25,
        "Data2" => 238.75,
        "Data3" => 95.50,
        "Data4" => 300.50,
        "Data5" => 286.80,
        "Data6" => 148.25
    ),
    array(

    )
);

$sumArray = array(); // Create an empty array to store the sum of each sub-array
foreach ($bar_chart_data as $subArray) {
    $sum = 0; // Initialize sum as zero
    foreach ($subArray as $key=>$value) {
        $sum += $value;
    }
    $sumArray[] = $sum; // Append each sum to the array
}

print_r($sumArray); // Print the array containing the sums.
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need one loop, then extract the values at index `1` and sum them:

```
foreach($bar_chart_data as $values) {
    $sumArray[] = array_sum(array_column($values, 1));
}
```

You can add the `$k => $values` back and use `$sumArray[$k]` if needed, but the way your array is shown it will work without it.